# Create tag for the new Inbox by Gmail

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Would it be possible to create a new tag for Inbox by Gmail (http://inbox.google.com)?

[google-inbox](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-inbox)?

Google is sending out invitations to more and more users, so it probably going to be useful in the near future.

Example question:

- [Mark all old reminders "done" in Inbox by Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/69580/mark-all-old-reminders-done-in-inbox-by-gmail)

Comment: Do you have some questions where you think this tag would be useful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one: [inbox-by-gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inbox-by-gmail).

Generally speaking, we only create tags when there are questions to put it on. The system doesn't allow for tags to be created ahead of time.